# Alibaba interview: print a sentence with min spaces

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary

I saw this interview question and gave a go. I got stuck. The interview question is:

> Given a string
>
> ```
> var s = "ilikealibaba";
> ```
>
> and a dictionary
>
> ```
> var d = ["i", "like", "ali", "liba", "baba", "alibaba"];
> ```
>
> try to give the s with min space
>
> The output may be
>
> 1. i like alibaba (2 spaces)
> 2. i like ali baba (3 spaces)
>
> but pick no.1

I have some code, but got stuck in the printing.
If you have better way to do this question, let me know.

```
function isStartSub(part, s) {
  var condi = s.startsWith(part);
  return condi;
}

function getRestStr(part, s) {
  var len = part.length;
  var len1 = s.length;
  var out = s.substring(len, len1);
  return out;
}

function recPrint(arr) {
    if(arr.length == 0) {
        return '';
    } else {
        var str = arr.pop();
        return str + recPrint(arr);
    }

}

// NOTE: have trouble to print
// Or if you have better ways to do this interview question, please let me know
function myPrint(arr) {
    return recPrint(arr);
}

function getMinArr(arr) {
    var min = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    var index = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var sub = arr[i];
        if(sub.length < min) {
            min = sub.length;
            index = i;
        } else {

        }   
    }

    return arr[index];  
}

function rec(s, d, buf) {
    // Base
    if(s.length == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
    
    } 

    for(var i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
        var subBuf = [];

        // baba
        var part = d[i];
        var condi = isStartSub(part, s);

        if(condi) {
            // rest string  
      var restStr = getRestStr(part, s);
      rec(restStr, d, subBuf);
            subBuf.unshift(part);
            buf.unshift(subBuf);
        } else {

        }       
    } // end loop

}

function myfunc(s, d) {
    var buf = [];
    rec(s, d, buf);

    console.log('-- test --');
    console.dir(buf, {depth:null});

    return myPrint(buf);    
}


// Output will be
// 1. i like alibaba (with 2 spaces)
// 2. i like ali baba (with 3 spaces)
// we pick no.1, as it needs less spaces
var s = "ilikealibaba";
var d = ["i", "like", "ali", "liba", "baba", "alibaba"];
var out = myfunc(s, d);
console.log(out);
```

Basically, my output is, not sure how to print it....

```
[ [ 'i', [ 'like', [ 'alibaba' ], [ 'ali', [ 'baba' ] ] ] ] ]
```

Comment: d is not a dictionary, it's an array.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut I'm pretty sure they meant "dictionary" as a non-technical term ("a collection of words").

Comment: It's a classic exercise in dynamic programming - I think it's a part of either Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms" or "The Algorithm Design Manual" but I remember in seeing it in one of those.

Comment: You could use a Trie data structure

Answer (score 3):

This problem is best suited for a dynamic programming approach. The subproblem is, "what is the best way to create a prefix of `s`". Then, for a given prefix of `s`, we consider all words that match the end of the prefix, and choose the best one using the results from the earlier prefixes.

Here is an implementation:

```js
var s = "ilikealibaba";
var arr = ["i", "like", "ali", "liba", "baba", "alibaba"];

var dp = []; // dp[i] is the optimal solution for s.substring(0, i)
dp.push("");

for (var i = 1; i <= s.length; i++) {
    var best = null; // the best way so far for s.substring(0, i)

    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        var word = arr[j];
        // consider all words that appear at the end of the prefix
        if (!s.substring(0, i).endsWith(word))
            continue;

        if (word.length == i) {
            best = word; // using single word is optimal
            break;
        }

        var prev = dp[i - word.length];
        if (prev === null)
            continue; // s.substring(i - word.length) can't be made at all

        if (best === null || prev.length + word.length + 1 < best.length)
            best = prev + " " + word;
    }
    dp.push(best);
}

console.log(dp[s.length]);
```

Comment: This question is not tagged Java. Please translate it to javascript.

Comment: This is the only answer of the 4 currently here that will actually produce a guaranteed optimal solution.

Comment: What happens if the dictionary has 1,000,000 entries and the string has 1000 characters?

Answer (score 2):

pkpnd's answer is along the right track. But word dictionaries tend to be quite large sets, and iterating over the entire dictionary at every character of the string is going to be inefficient. (Also, saving the entire sequence for each dp cell may consume a large amount of space.) Rather, we can frame the question, as we iterate over the string, as: given all the previous indexes of the string that had dictionary matches extending back (either to the start or to another match), which one is both a dictionary match when we include the current character, and has a smaller length in total. Generally:

```
f(i) = min(
  f(j) + length(i - j) + (1 if j is after the start of the string)
)
for all j < i, where string[j] ended a dictionary match
  and string[j+1..i] is in the dictionary
```

Since we only add another `j` when there is a match and a new match can only extend back to a previous match or to the start of the string, our data structure could be an array of tuples, `(best index this match extends back to, total length up to here)`. We add another tuple if the current character can extend a dictionary match back to another record we already have. We can also optimize by exiting early from the backwards search once the matched substring would be greater than the longest word in the dictionary, and building the substring to compare against the dictionary as we iterate backwards.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(str, dict){
  let m = [[-1, -1, -1]];
  
  for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    let best = [null, null, Infinity];
    let substr = '';
    let _i = i;
    
    for (let j=m.length-1; j>=0; j--){
      let [idx, _j, _total] = m[j];
      substr = str.substr(idx + 1, _i - idx) + substr;
      _i = idx;

      if (dict.has(substr)){
        let total = _total + 1 + i - idx;
      
        if (total < best[2])
          best = [i, j, total];
      }
    }

    if (best[0] !== null)
      m.push(best);
  }
  
  return m;
}


var s = "ilikealibaba";

var d = new Set(["i", "like", "ali", "liba", "baba", "alibaba"]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(s,d)));
```

We can track back our result:

```
[[-1,-1,-1],[0,0,1],[4,1,6],[7,2,10],[11,2,14]]

[11, 2, 14] means a total length of 14,
where the previous index in m is 2 and the right index
of the substr is 11
=> follow it back to m[2] = [4, 1, 6]
this substr ended at index 4 (which means the
first was "alibaba"), and followed m[1]
=> [0, 0, 1], means this substr ended at index 1
so the previous one was "like"
```

And there you have it: "i like alibaba"

Comment: This should indeed be faster in some cases, for 2 reasons: (1) when dictionary words are mostly long, there will be fewer inner loop iterations; (2) when the dictionary is large (probably much more likely) because hashtable lookups will be much faster than enumerating every dictionary word and testing.  BTW you could remove another O(n) factor by replacing the hash lookup with stepping through a trie built on the set of all reversed dictionary words -- then each lookup is genuinely O(1) instead of O(n) + amortised O(1).

Comment: @j_random_hacker not sure I follow the speedup you suggested. Could you please give an example? As I understand, in my current solution, the lookup of the substring in the dictionary set is O(1) but the construction of each substr is arbitrary, unknown in advance, although I've optimized its construction as we iterate backwards.

Comment: Sorry, claiming O(1) time per lookup was a mistake.  What I should have written was that, if you build a trie on the reversed dictionary strings, then at each starting position i, you can walk down the trie matching characters at text positions i, i-1, ..., checking only those j for which the trie indicates that str[j .. i] is a complete reversed dictionary word, and halting when no path exists in the trie.  But I don't think this would buy much.

Comment: @j_random_hacker perhaps building a trie out of the dictionary would make sense if the number of queries is expected to be large. The actual task we have, in general, can be summarized as which relevant dictionary words contain sequences of other dictionary words. But the greater the dictionary size, the more complex that question becomes.

Answer (score 1):

As you're asked to find a shortest answer probably [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) would be a possible solution. Or you could look into [A* Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Here is working example with A* (cause it's less bring to do than BFS :)), basically just copied from Wikipedia article. All the "turning string into a graph" magick happens in the `getNeighbors` function

https://jsfiddle.net/yLeps4v5/4/

```
var str = 'ilikealibaba'
var dictionary = ['i', 'like', 'ali', 'baba', 'alibaba']

var START = -1
var FINISH = str.length - 1

// Returns all the positions in the string that we can "jump" to from position i
function getNeighbors(i) {
    const matchingWords = dictionary.filter(word => str.slice(i + 1, i + 1 + word.length) == word)
    return matchingWords.map(word => i + word.length)
}

function aStar(start, goal) {
    // The set of nodes already evaluated
    const closedSet = {};

    // The set of currently discovered nodes that are not evaluated yet.
    // Initially, only the start node is known.
    const openSet = [start];

    // For each node, which node it can most efficiently be reached from.
    // If a node can be reached from many nodes, cameFrom will eventually contain the
    // most efficient previous step.
    var cameFrom = {};

    // For each node, the cost of getting from the start node to that node.
    const gScore = dictionary.reduce((acc, word) => { acc[word] = Infinity; return acc }, {})

    // The cost of going from start to start is zero.
    gScore[start] = 0

    while (openSet.length > 0) {
        var current = openSet.shift()
        if (current == goal) {
            return reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)
        }

        closedSet[current] = true;

        getNeighbors(current).forEach(neighbor => {
            if (closedSet[neighbor]) {
                return      // Ignore the neighbor which is already evaluated.
            }

            if (openSet.indexOf(neighbor) == -1) {  // Discover a new node
                openSet.push(neighbor)
            }

            // The distance from start to a neighbor
            var tentative_gScore = gScore[current] + 1
            if (tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]) {
                return      // This is not a better path.
            }

            // This path is the best until now. Record it!
            cameFrom[neighbor] = current
            gScore[neighbor] = tentative_gScore
        })
    }

    throw new Error('path not found')
}

function reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current) {
    var answer = [];
    while (cameFrom[current] || cameFrom[current] == 0) {
        answer.push(str.slice(cameFrom[current] + 1, current + 1))
        current = cameFrom[current];
    }
    return answer.reverse()
}

console.log(aStar(START, FINISH));
```

Comment: There is no graph in the question, so BFS and A* are nonsensical approaches (as they operate on graphs).

Comment: @pkpnd, **ilikealibaba** is the graph!

Comment: @BassemAkl Please specify the nodes and edges such that BFS is a correct approach.

Comment: Updated the answer with a more specific code example showing how to use graph lgorithms on tasks like this.

Comment: @pkpnd please see an updated answer (getNeighbors function does what you ask)

Comment: @pkpnd, you can generate them using an approach like this: foreach word in the array -> split(s) to sub_ss [now you have nodes and edges] -> foreach sub_s split (you should try here all combinations of orders of the words in the array.. finally you will get your graph.

Comment: @pkpnd, I think now it will work the `"abcdeg"` for my answer.

Comment: @nutic Downvote removed because this is now a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all possible combinations of the string by checking the starting  string and render then the result.

If more than one result has the minimum length, all results are taken.

It might not work for extrema with string who just contains the same base string, like `'abcabc'` and `'abc'`. In this case I suggest to use the shortest string and update any part result by iterating for finding longer strings and replace if possible.

```js
function getWords(string, array = []) {
    words
        .filter(w => string.startsWith(w))
        .forEach(s => {
            var rest = string.slice(s.length),
                temp = array.concat(s);
            if (rest) {
                getWords(rest, temp);
            } else {
                result.push(temp);
            }
        });
}


var string = "ilikealibaba",
    words = ["i", "like", "ali", "liba", "baba", "alibaba"],
    result = [];
    
getWords(string);

console.log('all possible combinations:', result);

console.log('result:', result.reduce((r, a) => {
    if (!r || r[0].length > a.length) {
        return [a];
    }
    if (r[0].length === a.length) {
        r.push(a);
    }
    return r;
}, undefined))
```

Comment: This approach is exponential time in the worst case (where there are exponentially-many elements in `result`), while a `O(N^2)` solution exists.

Comment: actually it stops if no words are found, because of the filtering.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. What if `string = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", words = ["a", "aa"]`? That example is small enough to fit in a comment but takes a couple seconds to run.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use trie data structure

1. Construct a trie data structure based on the dictionary data
2. Search the sentence for all possible slices and build a solution tree
3. Deep traverse the solution tree and sort the final combinations

```js
const sentence = 'ilikealibaba';
const words = ['i', 'like', 'ali', 'liba', 'baba', 'alibaba',];

class TrieNode {
    constructor() { }
    set(a) {
        this[a] = this[a] || new TrieNode();
        return this[a];
    }
    search(word, marks, depth = 1) {
        word = Array.isArray(word) ? word : word.split('');
        const a = word.shift();
        if (this[a]) {
            if (this[a]._) {
                marks.push(depth);
            }
            this[a].search(word, marks, depth + 1);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

TrieNode.createTree = words => {
    const root = new TrieNode();
    words.forEach(word => {
        let currentNode = root;
        for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            currentNode = currentNode.set(word[i]);
        }
        currentNode.set('_');
    });
    return root;
};

const t = TrieNode.createTree(words);

function searchSentence(sentence) {
    const marks = [];
    t.search(sentence, marks);
    const ret = {};
    marks.map(mark => {
        ret[mark] = searchSentence(sentence.slice(mark));
    });
    return ret;
}

const solutionTree = searchSentence(sentence);

function deepTraverse(tree, sentence, targetLen = sentence.length) {
    const stack = [];
    const sum = () => stack.reduce((acc, mark) => acc + mark, 0);
    const ret = [];
    (function traverse(tree) {
        const keys = Object.keys(tree);
        keys.forEach(key => {
            stack.push(+key);
            if (sum() === targetLen) {
                const result = [];
                let tempStr = sentence;
                stack.forEach(mark => {
                    result.push(tempStr.slice(0, mark));
                    tempStr = tempStr.slice(mark);
                });
                ret.push(result);
            }
            if(tree[key]) {
                traverse(tree[key]);
            }
            stack.pop();
        });
    })(tree);
    return ret;
}

const solutions = deepTraverse(solutionTree, sentence);

solutions.sort((s1, s2) => s1.length - s2.length).forEach((s, i) => {
    console.log(`${i + 1}. ${s.join(' ')} (${s.length - 1} spaces)`);
});
console.log('pick no.1');
```